# Use cmd commands in QT

Tags: qt

Hi i was checking and anyone can use commands very similar in cmd like dir mkdir etc.
But for example when i try to use command (cd ..) i couldn't

```
QProcess consola;
consola.start("cmd.exe /C " + comando);
consola.waitForFinished();
consola.waitForReadyRead();
```

This is the question how i can use more commands in cmd for qt for example.

Answer (score 0):

At least from the command line:

```
cmd /C "cd \"
```

works as did directories other than root. (Note the parenthesis around the command since it contains embedded spaces.) However, this example isn't very useful because this executes the command shell, changes the directory in that command shell, and then the command shell disappears, and your current directory is back to where you started.

I recommend looking into the QDir class, which has methods such as "current ()" and "setCurrent ()" for getting and setting the current directory. There are equivalents for mkdir and many others. Also, using QDir is much more cross-platform friendly, where using the "cmd" shell is Windows-specific.

You don't say what you're trying to accomplish, so beyond that suggestion, it's impossible to know how to best help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your process's current directory can be and mostly is different than current directory of your is running. Please read [chdir manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) for that.

That command is mostly working but changing the current directory of your process.